# Armature deform without the bone roll

Tags: rigging

I have a rig with a human wearing a coat, the problem is, rolling the hand twists the sleeve too much. I still need the sleeve to react to the hand moving, is there a way to have the armature deform the mesh without the bone roll? Outside of adding a bone that follows the hand bone without rolling?[image]

Comment: I suspect you need to tune the weight painting.  Some of the sleeve's vertices are in the same vertex group as the part of the hand controlled by the bone.  You can try removing them completely or at least reducing the weight that's assigned so the sleeve responds less.

Comment: That's the thing, I still need the sleeve to react to the hand, without twisting around it. In the end I use a bone with a damped track that follows the bone without rolling, just wondering if there's an easier way.

Comment: maybe add a bone to control only this part of the sleeve?

Comment: That's exactly what I did, I was just wondering about a simplier solution.